# Couple of questions from Takeuti's Proof Theory book

Tags: logic, proof-theory

I am reading [Gaisi Takeuti's Proof Theory](http://books.google.at/books/about/Proof_Theory.html?id=Idl6K-W69NYC) (Second Edition, Dover), and I have a couple of questions:

I) Right after the first (1.1.) definition, the author says that "*In any case it is essential that each set of variables is infinite...*". Why is that, i.e., what happens if the number of variables is finite?

II) Definition 1.6. (p. 8) defines (*fully*) *indicated term*. I find it very confusing. What is the difference between a non-indicated and an indicated term? Can there be a term in a formula that is not indicated?

III) Why is there a need for a proof using induction of Proposition 1.7. (p. 8)? The proposition says:

> If $A(a)$ is a formula (in which $a$ is not necessarily fully indicated), and $x$ is a bound variable not occurring in $A(a)$, then $\forall x A(x)$ and $\exists x A(x)$ are formulas.

Shouldn't this follow from the definition of the formula; more precisely of $\forall x A$ and $\exists x A$?

Thank you for the answers.

Comment: Do you expect us to take the book, go to the indicated pages, read and understand what's going on there and then *answer* you? I think odds are this won't happen much. Better: focus on one thing, write and define what you exactly want, write your own work and then wait.

Comment: For I) - if you had a finite number of variables, say only 3 (for the sake of example), it's impossible to express many formulas, like, "there are 4 numbers which are pairwise different".

Comment: @Timbuc: Do you suggest that I create a self-contained question for each of these points? The problem is that each of these questions is quite short/simple. However, I don't know any other place to discuss these things. Otherwise, I can always try to give more context to the existing question.

Comment: @Wojowu: I understand that if you allow only 3 variables, you cannot express many formulas. However, I am confused by the fact that any (finite) formula requires *only* finite number of variables.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding I), the "potential supply" of variables must be "unlimited", basically for two reason :

- in order to be able to build formulae satisfiable in domain with **any finite number** of elements;
- in order to avoid problems with substitution; if an attempted substitution can cause problems due to the "clash" with existing quantifiers, an unlimited supply of variables can gives us the certainty of finding a "new" one not already occurring into the formula.

Regarding II), we can consider the formula $B := (x=0)$ and the term $0$. Then we get $A := B[^x_0] := (0=0)$ by replacement of the term $0$ in place of the free variable $x$.

In $A$, the term $0$ is not fully-indicated, because it is not true that "every occurrence of [the term] $t$ [in $A$] is obtained by such a replacement".

---

---

*Regarding III), I'm perplexed* ...

We have to take into account the "role" of *indicated* variables; see the quantifier rules [page 10] :

Consider :

> **2.5** : the rule for $\forall$-right; we have that the "move" from $F(a)$ to $\forall x F(x)$ is applied with $a$ *fully indicated*. This means that we have to replace **all** occurrences of $a$ in $F(a)$ with $x$ [e.g. from $(a=a)$ to $\forall x(x=x)$].

Consider instead :

> **2.6** : the rule for $\exists$-right; now in the "move" from $F(t)$ to $\exists x F(x)$ "not every $t$ in $F(t)$ is necessarily indicated". This means that we can "remove" from $F(t)$ only **some** and not all occurrences of $t$ [e.g. from $(t=t)$ to $\exists x(x=t)$].

If we step back to **Def.1.3** [page 6] of quantified formulae, we have that they are built-up from e.g. $A := (a=0)$, to $A' := A[^a_x] := (x=0)$, to $\exists xA' := \exists x(x=0)$,

> "where $A'$ is obtained from $A$ by writing $x$ in place of $a$ at each occurrence of $a$ in $A$."

In conclusion, I think that the "perplexing" **Prop.1.7** [page 8] is aimed to license us to "remove" the above "snytactical" restriction; if we stay with **Def.1.3**, a formula like $\exists x (x=a)$ cannot be "produced" from : $(a=a)$ [see **Def.1.2**, page 6 : "every free variable is a term"].

Comment: I) But any formula (proof) can be expressed by a finite number of variables, because any formula (proof) is finite - or am I missing something.

Comment: II) What I don't fully understand is the idea of indicated term in a formula. Is the idea that some term is indicated in formula A w.r.t. to formula B from which it was produced? Because otherwise I don't understand how a term can be non-indicated.

Comment: III) I agree that formula $\exists x(x = a)$ cannot be produced from $a=a$, but it can be from $b=a$, by replacing *each occurrence* of $b$ by $x$.

Comment: @PeroP - YES, *finite* but "how much" finite ? We have no upper bound to the lenght of a formula, thus we need an "unlimited" supply of variables ... If we assume only 1.000 free variavles, you cannot write a formula satisfied in a universe with at least 1.001 elements.

Comment: @PeroP - At III) : YES, but (my conjecture) ... if in the proof we have derived $a=a$, we are lost ...